# Parsing CSS with jSoup

Tags: java, css, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse CSS DOM in Java and am already using jSoup for the same function for HTML.  I was looking through the jSoup API (as well as Google, of course) but didn't find any CSS-related parsing classes.  Is there a way to parse the CSS format into a DOM using jSoup or do I need a different API?

Comment: No, Jsoup cannot parse CSS, so you will have to look for something else (Unfortunately there are not many good options though), or use regex to process the CSS, if it is feasible.

Answer (score 3):

Jsoup cannot traverse the CSS DOM, although you can access it by selecting on the style/link tags.

Take a look at [CSS Parser](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/), it looks very promising.

```
    InputSource source = new InputSource(
        new StringReader(
            "h1 { background: #ffcc44; } div { color: red; }"));
    CSSOMParser parser = new CSSOMParser(new SACParserCSS3());
    CSSStyleSheet sheet = parser.parseStyleSheet(source, null, null);
    CSSRuleList rules = sheet.getCssRules();
    for (int i = 0; i < rules.getLength(); i++) {
        final CSSRule rule = rules.item(i);
        System.out.println(rule.getCssText());
    }
```

Output

```
h1 { background: rgb(255, 204, 68) }
div { color: red }
```